# JBPM: Is it not possible to call a service method with no argument from a Service task in bpmn?

Tags: jbpm, bpmn, bpmn.io

I am trying to invoke a no argument method of an Interface implementation via Service task. The eclipse JBPM plugin allows to create a Service task without providing the input arguments, but at runtime it fails with NullPointerException while loading the process definition stating operation arguments are not defined. So, does that mean I can not call a no argument service method via Service task of a work flow process?

Comment: How is this related to bpmn.io?

Answer (score 0):

According to BPMN principles, it is if course possible to envoke a service task without input arguments, see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/tasks/service-task/

A null pointer exception might point to a (java) (syntax) problem, but without a full error message, it is rather hard to determine what could be wrong.

Comment: From class org.jbpm.bpmn2.xml.ServiceTaskHandler the following piece of code breaks if I do not provide the inMessage and outMessage.

(workItemNode.getWork().getParameter("ParameterType")==null){workItemNode.getWork().setParameter("ParameterType",operation.getMessage().getType());}